# App crashes when trying to obtain photos from photo library via Image picker

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, photolibrary

Anyone encountered this error before when trying to access the photo library using the image picker?

```
NSInvalidArgumentException  Cannot set metadata in read-only store.
```

Any advise on what actually went wrong and suggestions on how I can resolve this will be greatly appreciated.

A snapshot of the error stack is shown below

[image]

Comment: Can you show some lines of code that illustrate how you're setting up your UIImagePickerController?

Comment: Did you figure this out? In my case it happens in production and I don't have the full log only "NSInvalidArgumentException: Cannot set metadata in read-only store." But it happens very infrequently. i.e. once out of more than 17000 sessions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a [post on the dev forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/546621) which might be slightly helpful (it's curiously marked "Apple Confidential Information" despite iOS 5 being released).

We've been seeing these too. My first impression was that it was related to using PhotoStream while not being connected to iCloud, but "recordVersion:forStore:" suggests it's trying to upgrade the photo library to the 5.0 format (which it presumably can't do as an unprivileged/sandboxed/etc process).

In addition to "sync with iTunes", the following things might fix the problem:

- Launching Photos
- Launching Camera and taking a picture

This doesn't seem to have been fixed in OS 5.0.1, but the number of reports has drastically reduced, suggesting people's photo libraries are eventually being upgraded.

Answer (score 4):

This issue is IOS5 only- have asked Apple on the dev forums, but no answer. I have not been able to repro myself, but..

My beta testers reported that syncing with iTunes seems to clear this error up- so my guess is that iTunes sync is fixing a permissions problem.

I wrapped this code in a @try/@catch but it's still crashing :(.

```
- (void)showImagePicker {
 UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];     
 imagePicker.delegate = self;
 imagePicker.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
 imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
 imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
 [tabController presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];  // sometimes crash 
}
```

also getting the same crash infrequently/non-reproducibly for other users when I call UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum